# Succinct Synonym for "Multi-use" or "Reusable"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

I am trying to find a laconic and "ringy" synonym for the word "multi-use" or "reusable". The word needs to be an adjective. To give you an idea of the context, think of a sheet of paper on which one can write, then erase what was written and then write again. It is this property that I am wanting to capture with the word.

---

Added from comments:

I feel like the word re-useable carries too generic of a meaning. I would like something related to writing, paper, sheets, etc., if it is possible. Think "emptyable" or something like that. I am trying to zero in on the erasability property. I … feel like there is something better than "eraseable" or "erasable".

Edit (Providing an example of intended usage):
"The notebook, filled with ____ pages, was paradisiacal for a detail-obsessed and correction-prone writer."

Comment: perhaps you could also tell us why words like “reusable” are no good.  It seems to have exactly the meaning you’re looking for.

Comment: I feel like the word re-useable carries too generic of a meaning. I would like something related to writing, paper, sheets, etc if it is possible. :-)

Comment: ***eraseable*** implies re-use.

Comment: I am not saying that it does not. I just feel like there is something better than that.

Comment: Think "emptyable" or something like that.

Comment: Go through the synonyms you find at thesaurus.com and explain to us what you find wrong with them.

Comment: A sheet can have multiple ways one can use it. However, i am trying to zero in on the erasability property.

Comment: So you're talking about a "magic slate".  I'm afraid it's already been invented.

Comment: "Green" is the current in-word.

Comment: Surely, palimpsest :)

Comment: Hi, Mad Physicist. Can you edit your question to include a sample sentence showing how you would use the word? You can put a ___ or other placeholder where you want the word to go. That will help people figure out exactly what you want. It's also technically required for single-word-requests, and will keep your question from being closed. I'm also going to edit your comments into the question, to provide more context; feel free to roll back or modify the edit when you add your example.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps **Versatile**
1. Capable of doing many things competently.
2. Having varied uses or serving many functions:
"The most versatile of vegetables is the tomato" (Craig Claiborne).
3. Variable or inconstant; changeable: a versatile temperament.
4. Biology Capable of moving freely in all directions, as the loosely attached anthers of certain flowers.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/versatile

Answer (score 2):

> **wipeable**
>
> *Adjective*
>
> able to be wiped
>   <sub>[Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/wipeable)</sub>

The term is used to describe whiteboards, where the ink from the dry erase markers can be wiped, leaving the whiteboard clean and ready to reuse.  Here's a patent describing an eraser for a "wipeable marker medium."

> The connector surface is engagable with an end of the dry erase marker which is opposite a dispenser for the wipeable marker medium.
>   <sub>[Combination support and eraser for a dry erase marker 
>   US 5957603 A](https://www.google.ch/patents/US5957603)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**ever-use** would be a coined term that might get at what you're hoping. Others might be  "ever-write", or "ever-sheet", or "ever-blank" . (or as the OP brought up in a comment based on this "ever" suggestion, perhaps "ever-use page" or even, in a coined way, "ever-page".)  Then there is also the famous "ever-lastin

Or, perhaps **ever** alone

This is more of a coined term...maybe even a made up word, although I do believe you are permitted to form a compound adjective verb combo to create a new adjective.  The Oxford dictionary gives an example(last one) of that use

> [***Ever*** from Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ever)
>
> 2) At all times; always.
>
> *‘ever the man of action, he was impatient with intellectuals’*
>
> *‘caravan holidays remain as popular as ever’*
>
> *emphasized text*‘they lived happily ever after’
>
> in combination : *‘he toyed with his ever-present cigar’*

edit

Not sure why I didn't think of it before but, in the same vein, there is also

> [***everlasting*** from Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/everlasting)
>
> Lasting forever or a very long time.
>
> ‘the damned would suffer everlasting torment’
>
> ‘an everlasting reminder of this evening’

There was the famous "everlasting gobstopper" in Willie Wonka and the Chocolate Factory

Comment: I like it :-) were you thinking "ever-use page" or "ever-page"?

Comment: Yes, I included a few examples...didn't list ever-page, but sure I could put in "ever-page" .. I stopped after a few but I was suggesting that many could be possible and figured you'd know what you wanted to emphasize in terms of where it would be applied.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could borrow a term
from [optical disc technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD-RW) — “rewritable.” 
Or, in the same vein, “multi-write,” “refreshable” or “renewable.”